# Extract min max date of a row with multiple dates

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

How can I split the min and the max date which is located in a row with multiplate dates

This is in Power Query

```
8/31/2018, 8/29/2018, 4/9/2018, 8/29/2018, 8/29/2018
```

Result in different Columns

```
min            max
29/8/2019      4/9/2019
```

Can anybody help me to figure it out?

Code:
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom4", {"FechaFinalTarea", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stjaB.png)

Full code:
let
    Source = Etapa_1_Caricam,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Num Form"}, {{"mynewtable", each _, type table [Num Form=text, DupForm=text, Creado En=date, FechaCreac=date, SLA=number, Initiator Name=text, Business Unit=text, BU Description=text, Tipo Form=text, Descripción del proyecto=text, Texto tarea=text, Field12=number, Task Assigned=text, Status=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Task_Etapa1", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Texto tarea")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Task_Etapa1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Iniciador", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Initiator Name")),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Iniciador", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values1", {{"Iniciador", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(*, ", "), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", "Custom", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Descripción del proyecto")),
    #"Extracted Values2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values2", "Text Before Delimiter", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Custom], ","), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter",{"Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Text Before Delimiter", "Descripcion del Proyecto"}}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "FechaInicio", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Creado En")),
    #"Extracted Values3" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom3", {"FechaInicio", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values3", "Text Before Delimiter", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([FechaInicio], ", "), type text),
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter1", "Text After Delimiter", each Text.AfterDelimiter([FechaInicio], ", "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Text After Delimiter",{"Text After Delimiter", "Text Before Delimiter"}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns1", {{"FechaInicio", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(*, ", "), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "FechaFinalTarea", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"FechaCreac")),
    #"Extracted Values4" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom4", {"FechaFinalTarea", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no date `29/8/2019` in your input data (or any date relating to the year 2019). You've also presented one of your "results" as `day/month/year`. This may just be a couple of typos, but makes both your "results" and question are unclear and harder to follow.

One of the approaches below should work, if I've understood correctly.

---

If your initial table is something like the below (where all the dates are in `month/day/year` format and are part of a single comma-delimited string):

[image: Input table]

then I get this output (note the columns `min` and `max`):

[image: Output table]

using this code:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({{"8/31/2018, 8/29/2018, 4/9/2018, 8/29/2018, 8/29/2018"}}),
    split = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "datesToCheck", each List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1], ","), each Date.FromText(_, "en-US")), type list),
    minAndMax = Table.AddColumn(split, "toExpand", each [min = List.Min([datesToCheck]), max = List.Max([datesToCheck])], type record),
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(minAndMax, "toExpand", {"min", "max"})
in
    expanded
```

---

However, if your initial table is something like the below (where the dates are in their own columns to begin with):

[image: Input table]

then I get this output (note the columns `min` and `max`):

[image: Output table]

using the code below:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({List.Transform({"8/31/2018", "8/29/2018", "4/9/2018", "8/29/2018", "8/29/2018"}, each Date.FromText(_, "en-US"))}),
    split = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "datesToCheck", each Record.FieldValues(_), type list),
    minAndMax = Table.AddColumn(split, "toExpand", each [min = List.Min([datesToCheck]), max = List.Max([datesToCheck])], type record),
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(minAndMax, "toExpand", {"min", "max"})
in
    expanded
```

---

Based on your code, it seems your table contains a table column (called `mynewtable`), within which there is a column named `FechaCreac`, which itself contains dates. I can't test this, but I recommend that you replace these lines in your code:

```
  #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "FechaFinalTarea", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"FechaCreac")),
  #"Extracted Values4" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom4", {"FechaFinalTarea", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
  #"Extracted Values4"
```

with:

```
  #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "FechaFinalTarea", each let dates = Table.Column([mynewtable],"FechaCreac") in [min = List.Min(dates), max = List.Max(dates)]),
  expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom4", "FechaFinalTarea", {"min", "max"})
in
  expanded
```

and that should then show you `min` and `max` columns.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, I have tried, with the code you've sent and it worked perfectly, however when i do it in my initial table it does not  work.  this is my code

Comment: @BenCruz, if you include your code in your question, I'll try to see why it's not working.

Comment: @BenCruz, see the end of my answer to see what replacements I think you need to make.